# Prove that the area of a nellipse can be computed using an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was told to provide a proof on why the area of an ellipse whose equation is $$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} = 1$$
Can be calculated using the integral
$$ A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}a\, b\, cos^{2}(t)\,dt $$
My approach was to make use of the parameterization
$x = a^2\,cos\,t$, $y = b^2\,sen\,t$ and then try to do something like $$ A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}D(t)\,dt $$
Such that $D (t) $ is the distance from the point $t$ to the origin. However, I was no able to provide a proof. I was wondering that maybe there is an easier way to approach this.

Sorry if there are grammar mistakes, I am not a native speaker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One point to note here is that the area is given by $A=ab\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 t\,dt$. But the second term is the case $a=b=1$, i.e., the area of the unit disk. So in essence all you're showing is that a unit disk has area $\pi$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Due to the symmetry of the problem, the problem is reduced to solve
\begin{align*}
A = 2\int_{-a}^{a}\sqrt{b^{2}\left(1 - \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}\right)}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

which can be computed based on the substitution $x = a\sin(t)$:
\begin{align*}
A & = 2ab\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1 - \sin^{2}(t)}\cos(t)\mathrm{d}t\\\\
& = 2ab\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2}(t)\mathrm{d}t\\\\
& = ab\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}[\cos(2t) + 1]\mathrm{d}t\\\\
& = 2ab\int_{0}^{\pi/2}[\cos(2t) + 1]\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: (+1) Note that the ellipse is also symmetric about the $x$-axis, so your starting integral can be further reduced to $4\int_0^a \sqrt{b^2\left(1-x^2/a^2\right)} dx$.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say $y$-axis in my comment.